# Unable to echo password

Tags: php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['$P']."<BR>";       

?>


    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="password" name="p">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I am unable to echo the password.  Not looking forward to security features etc., Just want to  know what exactly is wrong in this simple code

Comment: Try this: <?php echo $_POST['P']."<BR>"; ?>

Comment: uppercase tags!!! Oh the horror!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's

```
echo $_POST['p']."<BR>";
```

probably. Do a

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and you'll see what the names are.

Comment: LOL...YES! how silly of me...thanks.

Have to wait 12 mins to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
<?php
echo $_POST['p']."<BR>";       
?>


<form method="post" action="DONT_FORGET_URL.php">
<input type="password" name="p" value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```